# Can "what" mean "what role" in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

I'd like to know if "what" could convey the meaning of "what role" in the sentence below as "what role others expect from us" is mentioned.

> As a flight attendant, my uniform can imply both **what role** others expect from me and **what I should play**.

Comment: Have you looked at the meaning of 'role' in a dictionary?

Comment: Your proposed sentence is very ambiguous.

Comment: My immediate interpretation of the sentence was that her uniform had a picture of a banjo on it, indicating the musical instrument she should be playing—in her revised role as flight-attendant entertainer. I'm actually not joking. By the time I got to the end of the sentence and read **what I should play** I immediately though of a banjo. (Why a banjo, I don't know. But there was a clear correlation between *play* and *music*.) If you repeat **role**, there's no chance of that interpretation.

Comment: I agree with Jason. I didn't think of a banjo - I wondered if you were going to play football!

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica I thought of a grand piano, then realised that it wouldn't fit down the aisle of the plane.

Comment: The problem is not the use of _what_, but the use of _play_ only in the second clause. The first clause should be _what role others expect me to play_ instead of _what role others expect from me_. If you make them parallel, it all falls out.

Answer (score 0):

> I'd like to know if "what" could convey the meaning of "what role" in
> the sentence below as "what role others expect from us" is mentioned.
>
> As a flight attendant, my uniform can imply both what role others
> expect from me and what I should play

No, it doesn't work. "What" never refers backward, it always refers forward. Instead use "that" to refer back.

One way to make it clear would be:

*As a flight attendant, my uniform can imply both what role others expect from me and **that which** I should play.*

Alternatively:

*As a flight attendant, my uniform can imply both **the** role others expect from me and **the one** I should play.*

or

*As a flight attendant, my uniform can imply both what others expect from me and what role I should play.*

Comment: I'm fairly happy with 'As a flight attendant, my uniform can imply both which role others expect from me, and which I should play'. Less happy with 'what' here as there is the determiner/pronoun zeugma. Have you an authority supporting ' "What" never refers backward, it always refers forward'?

Comment: Have you an authority supporting ' "What" never refers backward, it always refers forward'? I'll take that as a 'no'.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth - Is that a genuine question? I'll take *that* as a no!  :-)

Comment: Yes, it is. Unanswered for many months. I take it you're saying that determiner 'what' can't be used without a NP, unlike 'which', where the second NP may be omitted.

Comment: Looking back, it was a rather broad statement. Maybe I should have said, I can't *think* of a case where it refers backward. I am always open to a counterexample.

Comment: I think your assumption is very likely to be correct, actually ... just being thorough.   << which N I ... and which I ....>> in this type of sentence _must_ be read as a deletion (N after the second 'which'). But << << what N I ... and what I ....>> I think (only think) _must_ be taken as an undeleted string, with the second 'what' a pronoun.

Answer (score 0):

As I interpret it, the sentence states an interesting concept, but it could be clearer:

"As a flight attendant, my uniform can imply what role I should play and what role others expect me to play."

The uniform tells the flight attendant herself what her duties should be, but others may see the flight attendant in another light, and so see her duties differently.

If in the above sentence "role" were omitted, you would have

"As a flight attendant, my uniform can imply what I should play and what others expect me to play."

This works, but it makes more of a demand on the reader to interpret it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really clear. To drop words, you need more parallelism. If you had the same subject, it work much better. For instance, if you say "I don't know what clothes I should bring, and what I should leave", it's clear that both "what" refer to clothes.

Comment: I'd say 'which' sounds more natural here.

Answer (score 0):

No.
The word "role" is not implicitly recalled here.

And it is even expected to NOT be "role" as it is an other prepositions that is meant to complete the first.
so here "What you should (verb)" is understood as... anything that correlate with what we imagine a flight intendant must (verb) to fullfil it's role.

Do : guide passenger, give safety rules, etc...

Play : an instrument for entertainment?

Focus on : weird passager behavior, people asking you, things that could trouble confort of all, people seeking help with luggages, etc ...

Behave : nicely etc..

It's a correlation, not a repetition, that is implied here.